# React-widgets DateTimePicker not working giving error of cannot assign to to type 'Readonly<DateTimePickerProps>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, semantic-ui-react, react-final-form, react-widgets

Hi I am new to TypeScript. I am not able to understand this error. If anyone can help that will be greatly appriciated. I tried to google the issue and tried to change the version of it as well but not sure what is causing this error. I am using this date picker in my `semantic-ui-react` with `react-final-form`. My DateInput component is giving me an issue on my `DateTimePicker` import. `react-final form` is working well for other inputs. just issue with this `react widgets`->`DateTimePicker`.
**This is the error**

```
TypeScript error in C:/Users/brahm/source/repos/FullStack/SOCIALMEDIA-react-asp.netcore/Reactivities/client-app/src/app/common/form/DateInput.tsx(22,8):
Type '{ readOnly: any; as?: any; children?: ReactNode; className?: string | undefined; content?: ReactNode; control?: any; disabled?: boolean | undefined; error?: SemanticShorthandItem<LabelProps>; ... 9 more ...; time: any; }' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<DateTimePickerProps>'.
  Types of property 'id' are incompatible.
    Type 'string | number | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.
      Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.  TS2322
```

**This is my DateInput Component**

```
import { FieldRenderProps } from 'react-final-form';
import { FormFieldProps, Form, Label } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import { DateTimePicker } from 'react-widgets';

interface IProps
  extends FieldRenderProps<Date, HTMLInputElement>,
    FormFieldProps {}

const DateInput: React.FC<IProps> = ({
  input,
  width,
  date = false,
  time = false,[![enter image description here][1]][1]
  placeholder,
  meta: { touched, error },
  ...rest
}) => {
  return (
    <Form.Field error={touched && !!error} width={width}>
      <DateTimePicker
        placeholder={placeholder}
        value={input.value || null}
        onChange={input.onChange}
        date={date}
        time={time}
        {...rest}
      />
      {touched && error && (
        <Label basic color="red">
          {error}
        </Label>
      )}
    </Form.Field>
  );
};
export default DateInput;
```

**This is where it gets render**

```
    <Grid>
      <Grid.Column width={10}>
        <Segment clearing>
          <FinalForm
            onSubmit={handleFinalFormSubmit}
            render={({ handleSubmit }) => (
              <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <Field
                  name="title"
                  placeholder="Title"
                  value={activity.title}
                  component={TextInput}
                />
                <Field
                  name="discription"
                  placeholder="Description"
                  rows={3}
                  value={activity.discription}
                  component={TextAreaInput}
                />
                <Field
                  name="category"
                  placeholder="Catagory"
                  value={activity.category}
                  component={SelectInput}
                  options={category}
                />
                <Form.Group widths="equal">
                  <Field
                    component={DateInput}
                    name="date"
                    date={true}
                    placeholder="Date"
                    value={activity.date!}
                  />
                  <Field
                    component={DateInput}
                    name="time"
                    time={true}
                    placeholder="Time"
                    value={activity.date!}
                  />
                </Form.Group>

                <Field
                  name="city"
                  placeholder="City"
                  value={activity.city}
                  component={TextInput}
                />
                <Field
                  name="venue"
                  component={TextInput}
                  placeholder="Venue"
                  value={activity.venue}
                />
                <Button
                  loading={submiting}
                  floated="right"
                  positive
                  type="submit"
                  content="Submit"
                />
                <Button
                  onClick={() => history.push('/activities')}
                  floated="right"
                  type="button"
                  content="Cancel"
                />
              </Form>
            )}
          />
        </Segment>
      </Grid.Column>
    </Grid>
  );
};
export default observer(ActivityForm);
```

**This is the error**

Answer (score 1):

Also new to TypeScript, and taking Neil Cummings course too =). I removed this line and it seems to work fine:

```
<DateTimePicker enter code here
        placeholder={placeholder}
        value={input.value || null}
        onChange={input.onChange}
        onBlur={input.onBlur}
        onKeyDown={(e) => e.preventDefault()}
        date={date}
        time={time}
        //{...rest}
    />
```

It seems that the problem is related to the version of react-widget installed

Hope it works for you